# Conditional reverse proxy in apache

Tags: proxy, conditional-statements, reverse

if request comes from public ip 50.12.95.78. Proxypass to http://192.168.1.100/quote  url.

if request comes from other public ip . Proxypass to http://192.168.1.100/  url

What is the settings for it in apache?  Reverse proxy wont work in if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a conditional reverse proxy in Apache httpd by utilizing `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite`.

For instance, if you originally had your reverse proxy set up with the following configuration:

```
ProxyPass        / http://192.168.1.100/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.100/
```

It can be made conditional by using the [proxy flag on a RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p). An example configuration could look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}" =50.12.95.78
RewriteRule (.*) http://192.168.1.100/quote$1 [P,E=proxy_pass_path:/quote]
RewriteRule (.*) http://192.168.1.100$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.100${proxy_pass_path}/ interpolate
```

1. The first `RewriteRule` is applied and proxied only if the preceding
   `RewriteCond` directive is matched, i.e. if the Remote IP
   Address is 50.12.95.78.

   - The [P]roxy flag also prevents further `RewriteRule` directives from being applied.
   - The environmental variable *proxy_pass_path* is set to tell the `ProxyPathReverse` directive that the path has been modified.
2. The second `RewriteRule`
   is automatically applied if the first did not evaluate.
3. Finally, the
   `ProxyPathReverse` directive is modified to rewrite response headers
   based on the *proxy_pass_path* variable.

Going beyond the scope of your question, bear in mind that this kind of proxy will not implement any real form of security. IP addresses other than 50.12.95.78 will still be able to access `http://192.168.1.100/quote` simply by requesting `http://<Proxy_Host>/quote`.

Comment: for future reference, there are some additional docs at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html