# Subdomain reroute to domain

Tags: laravel, dns, subdomain, hosting, cpanel

I have created a web app using Laravel 8 and is hosted on **Server A** using domain name '**myapp.com**'. I have applied a wildcard subdomain eg: '**myweb1.myapp.com**' and '**myweb2.myapp.com**' for one of the app features.

I then purchased a domain '**myweb1.com**' from **Server B** which I intends to reroute it to '**myweb1.myapp.com**'. How do I achieve this?

So, when '**myweb1.myapp.com**' is entered the URL will reroute to '**myweb1.com**'. And '**myweb1.myapp.com/product**' will be '**myweb1.com/product**'.

Do I need to change the nameservers for '**myweb1.com**'? Do I need to change .htaccess for it? What if I only purchased a domain without a hosting which I can't edit .htaccess? Can I achieve this? And are there any specific term for I want to do?

Comment: When asking questions about domains, be specific. Which Registrar? Which DNS server? Show what you tried and the problem. If you do not understand how domains and DNS servers operate, do research first. There are lots of articles and videos on the Internet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with reverse proxy.

if your web server is nginx: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352958/5987259

if your web server is apache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52286695/5987259